# How to load vue in production mode when using vue.esm-bundler.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs3

I'm using Vue 3 with webpack, and loading it with vue.esm-bundler.js, because I have in-dom templates.

Docs say that with a bundler, "Leaves prod/dev branches with process.env.NODE_ENV guards (must be replaced by bundler)"

What does it mean? How should I accomplish this through webpack? I currently just setted the alias like:

```
config.resolve =  {
  alias: {
    esmvue$: path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules/vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js')
  }
}
```

But still I don't understand how to activate the production mode. I don't fully understand the meaning of the docs sentence above.

Comment: Do you have a specific problem when using it? You're supposed to set process.env.NODE_ENV as described

Comment: Hi, thank you. I don't understand 'as described'. What do you mean? Taking a look into vue.esm-bundler.js code, I see that it directly references process.env.NODE_ENV, but how is it made available to vue.esm-bundler.js? How can vue.esm-bundler.js read a nodejs constant?

Comment: It's not just node constant, it's real runtime variable, window.process.env.NODE_ENV. It's unknown what's your setup exactly but it exists at least in some setups. Any way, this bundle expects it to exist

Answer (score 0):

I've just realised that webpack (at least v5) automatically injects process.env.NODE_ENV into the bundled filed, both in dev and production mode.
process.env.NODE_ENV will be therefore available in vue.esm-bundler.js by default and nothing has to be done.

I also learned that probably before this feature, the way to do it was using the built in webpack DefinePlugin:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV),
});
```

Which still can be useful for setting other variables or constants in bundled files. For example some Vue configuration:

```
new webpack.DefinePlugin({
  __VUE_OPTIONS_API__: 'true',
  __VUE_PROD_DEVTOOLS__: 'false',
  __VUE_PROD_HYDRATION_MISMATCH_DETAILS__: 'false'
})
```